# How to get last 2 words (starting from the second-to-last space) from string?

Tags: c#, linq

My main string is,

" Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 20 TN 123 34"

I want to get "123 34" only from Main String.
I have done by the following code.

```
  string mainStr = " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 20 TN 123 34";
                string filterStr = mainStr.Substring(0, mainStr.LastIndexOf(" "));
                int sRange = filterStr.LastIndexOf(" ");
                string outputStr = mainStr.Substring(sRange+1);
```

How to be done by Linq way(just a single line is awesome)?

Comment: I don't think LINQ is particularly suited to this, since it's not really a collection-based operation. Personally, I'd favour readability.

Comment: I thought, to avoid some variable declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the last two elements using linq can be a bit unreadable, so I would suggest a multiline solution without `LastIndexOf` or `Substring`:

```
string mainStr = " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 20 TN 123 34";
var words = mainStr.Split();
var lastTwoWords = string.Join(" ", words.Skip(words.Length - 2));
```

If you really need it to be linq, you can use a combination of `Reverse` and `Take`:

```
var lastTwoWords = string.Join(" ", mainStr.Split().Reverse().Take(2).Reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

**With Linq:**

```
string mainStr = " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 20 TN 123 34";

var reverse = mainStr.Split(' ').Reverse();
string output = reverse.Take(1).Last() + " " + reverse.Take(2).Last();
```

you can use `LastOrDefault()`

**Better performance:**

```
int x1 = mainStr.Trim().IndexOf(" ");
int x2 = mainStr.Trim().LastIndexOf(" ");
int x3 = mainStr.Trim().LastIndexOf(" ", x2-1);

string firstWord = mainStr.Trim().Substring(0, x1);
string middleWord = mainStr.Trim().Substring(x1, x2 - x1);
string lastWord = mainStr.Trim().Substring(x2 + 1);
string output = mainStr.Trim().Substring(x3 + 1);  // returns 123 34
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd move what you already have into a separate method (and tidy it up a little bit):

```
public static string GetLast2Words(string mainStr)
{
    int position = mainStr.LastIndexOf(' ', mainStr.LastIndexOf(' ') - 1);
    return position >= 0 ? mainStr.Substring(position) : null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var outputStr = GetLast2Words(mainStr);
```

Alternatively, you could use regular expressions:

```
var outputStr = Regex.Match(mainStr, "\\s(\\S+\\s\\S+$)").Groups[0].Value;
```

- `\s` matches whitespace
- `\S` matches any character that isn't whitespace

Note that the regular expression method will output `string.Empty` if there isn't a match, whereas the first method will output null.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Linq**

If you really want to do in Linq, you can do following.

```
var list = mainStr.Split(new []{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Reverse().Take(2).Reverse();
```

But please note this would be not recommended due to two Reverse statements etc.

**Using RegEx**

A better option would be to use Regex

```
var result = Regex.Match(mainStr,@"(\w*)\s(\w*)*$").Value;
```

Output

```
123 34
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be the solution if you can get the length of the string.

```
string mainStr = " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 20 TN 123 34";
string filterStr = String.Concat(mainStr.Skip(mainStr.Count() - 6));
Console.WriteLine(filterStr);
```

Comment: @John I apologize, I changed the 2nd line so it now outputs 123 34.

Comment: After your edit, your code outputs "23 134" if we change the last 2 words to "123 134". You're approaching this incorrectly, I'm afraid.

Comment: @John So you want a solution that always outputs the last 2 words regardless of size. I apologize, my solution is wrong since it assumes that the total number of characters in the last two words will be known and always be the same.

Comment: A solution that always outputs the last 2 words would be equivalent to the code the question asker provided.